# Minimizing function in terms of integral - scipy

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize, function-fitting

I want to find the parameter of a function that will result in a specific integral value in a defined interval. To make things simpler, the example below considers the function to be a straight line, and the parameter I want to find is the slope `m`. I use `scipy.integrate.quad` to integrate and was trying to use `scipy.integrate.minimize` to find the slope:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.optimize import minimize

IntegralValue = 10
initial_guess = 0.1

def function(m):
    intgrl, abserr = quad(lambda x: m*x, 0, 10) # interval from 0 to 10
    return intgrl - IntegralValue
res = minimize(function, initial_guess, method='nelder-mead',options={'xtol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})

print(res.x)
```

A simple `0.2` should be the result (`function(0.2)` results in `0`), but for some reason I get a warning that the "maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded" and the output is something that doesn't make sense (`-6.338253e+27`). Default minimize method also did not work. Maybe I am missing something or misunderstood, but I couldn't figure it out. I appreciate the help. I am using Python 3.7.10 on Windows 10.

Comment: Dumb question: are you sure that zero is the _minimum_ of the `function`? Can `function` return negative values? I think `intgrl - IntegralValue` in general can easily be negative. If it can, `minimize` will try to find the lowest _negative_ value of this function, which may be negative infinity.

Comment: If that's a dumb question, I am even dumber. It makes total sense what you said and I think that is the problem... that means I have to put a constraint for non-negative value somehow, somewhere, right? Maybe just an ```abs()```...

Comment: Hint: minimizing `(intgrl - IntegralValue)**2` is equivalent to solving the equation `integrl = integralValue`.

Comment: I think the simplest thing is to return a different kind of distance between the two values: `abs(intgrl - IntegralValue)` or `(intgrl - IntegralValue)**2` maybe.

Comment: Thank you both, yea, I knew it was going to be something obvious 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum is of course negative infinity. To get a zero, I just had to constrain the problem to non negative values, as commented by @ForceBru and @joni. Thanks!

**EDIT**

here is the final functional full code:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.optimize import minimize

IntegralValue = 10
initial_guess = 0.1

def function(m):
    intgrl, abserr = quad(lambda x: m*x, 0, 10) # interval from 0 to 10
    return abs(intgrl - IntegralValue)
res = minimize(function, initial_guess, method='nelder-mead',options={'xtol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})

print(res.x)
```

Comment: It may be helpful for future generations to include a snippet of code that shows how to fix the issue - maybe a definition of `function` which now returns `abs` or `(...)**2`

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you describe is one of [*root finding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms); that is, you want to find `m` such that `function(m) = 0`.  The appropriate tool for such a problem is one of the [root finding functions](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/optimize.html#root-finding) in SciPy.

For example, you could use [`root_scalar`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root_scalar.html) as in  the following code, which uses your original function `function`:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.optimize import root_scalar


def function(m):
    intgrl, abserr = quad(lambda x: m*x, 0, 10) # interval from 0 to 10
    return intgrl - IntegralValue


IntegralValue = 10
guess_bracket = [0.0, 1.0]

res = root_scalar(function, x0=guess_bracket[0], x1=guess_bracket[1])

if res.converged:
    print(f"m = {res.root}")
else:
    print(f'root_scalar failed: res.flag={res.flag}')
```

Output:

```
m = 0.2
```